# Switch statement doesn't switch

Tags: android, switch-statement

I'm trying to change the value of a variable in a switch statement, with a spinner. But the variable is stuck on the default value. 
Here's the code with the switch statement, and how the variable is used.

```
    final Spinner feedbackSpinner = (Spinner) 
    findViewById(R.id.SpinnerFeedbackType);  

    String RSSFEEDOFCHOICE;
    switch((int)feedbackSpinner.getSelectedItemId())  {      
         case R.string.groep1:
        RSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "https://www.scouting.nl/publiek/nieuws?format=feed&type=rss";
         break;
         case R.string.groep2:
        RSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "https://www.scouting.nl/publiek/nieuws?format=feed&type=rss";
         break;
         case R.string.groep3:
        RSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "https://www.scouting.nl/publiek/nieuws?format=feed&type=rss";
         break;
         case R.string.groep4:
        RSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "https://www.scouting.nl/publiek/nieuws?format=feed&type=rss";
             break;
         default:           
             RSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "http://www.scout.org/rss/feed/all";
             break;
     }


    // get rss feed
    feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);

    UpdateDisplay();
        }

private RSSFeed getFeed(String urlToRssFeed)
```

I just don't get why the RSS feed doesn't change, while the variable should have changed.

Comment: This is **far** too much code for a StackOverflow question.  Please reduce this to the absolute minimum required to exhibit the problem (see http://sscce.org).

Comment: Have you checked that the code actually executes when you think it does?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your switch statement is in the onCreate method, this is called once when the activity is created. It has no sense there.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm sorry, I just reduced it

Comment: Try to print all the variables involved before and after the switch.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö Yes, I tried the code, it all works except the changing of RSS feed

Comment: @aromero I'm trying to change the value of RSSFEEDOFCHOICE using a spinner and a switch statement

Comment: Your logic is wrong. In your onCreate method you need to populate the spinner. Then, you need to handle the spinners onSelectedItemListener, and there is when you know that an item in the spinner was selected.

Comment: Log.i("", "Item id:" + feedbackSpinner.getSelectedItemId()); Log.i("", "String res id:" + R.string.groep1); Would help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

R.String. would return the ID of the resource and not the string which is inside your strings.xml therefore the comparison would fail. You might want to use  getString(R.string.hello) instead and remove the typecasting to int in the switch statement.

Comment: But then the value's would become strings, wich the switch statement can't handle, that's the reason of the typecasting to int.

Comment: In that case you can use the string-array for storing the strings in strings.xml and use switch over getItemAtPosition(pos). Instead of R.String.xyz you will need t owrite the integer positions (like 1,2,3).